# MySQL PDO has no errors, but not pulling data

Tags: mysql, pdo

Something funky is going on with my MySQL PDO query.

If I pass in an array of values, it does not.
If I don't pass in the arrays it works.

I know this because I get a PDO error 0000, but when I run 
     $num_events_months = $result_events_months->rowCount();

it only returns a value if the values are hard-coded into the query.

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong?

The following DOES NOT work:

```
$query_events_months = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m') AS event_month_year, DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%M') AS event_month_name FROM Events WHERE event_date >= :current_date AND status = :status GROUP BY event_month_year";
$result_events_months = $conn->prepare($query_events_months);
$result_events_months->execute(array(':current_date'=>'2014-10-01',':status'=>'published'));
```

The following DOES work:

```
$query_events_months = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m') AS event_month_year, DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%M') AS event_month_name FROM Events WHERE event_date >= '2014-10-01' AND status = 'published' GROUP BY event_month_year";
$result_events_months = $conn->prepare($query_events_months);
$result_events_months->execute(array(':current_date'=>'2014-10-01',
                                   ':status'=>'published'));
```

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried renaming `:current_date` ? There is a built-in function `CURRENT_DATE()` that might be causing a disturbance in the force!

Comment: How do you know there are no errors? Do you even check for them?

Answer (score 0):

`PDO ERROR 000` is the value returned when a query executed successfully.

You should only print when it fails, otherwise you should ignore.

In your case something along the lines:

```
if(!$result_events_months->execute(array(...))){
   var_dump($result_events_months->errorInfo()); //not outside of the failure block
}else{
   var_dump($result_events_months->fetchAll());
}
```

Comment: Hi meda, it is supposed to return 2 records.

Comment: @Hugo then you need to fetch them, the code you show only execute see update